# Wacom GUI for Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, gui, wacom

When I make my first Linux installation on my Thinkpad Yoga I choose stable Ubuntu16 TLS and after installation at ControlPanel I have found Wacom Stylus-Digitizer settings! But Ubuntu have too simple interface, so I prefer to use Kubuntu+Dolphin. After installing it Wacom Stylus works, but I can't configure it because of absent of WacomConfigurationGUI at CP. I already try many methods from internet but they does not work.

```
:~$ xsetwacom --list devices
Wacom Co.,Ltd. Pen and multitouch sensor Finger touch   id: 9   type: TOUCH     
Wacom Co.,Ltd. Pen and multitouch sensor Pen stylus     id: 10  type: STYLUS    
Wacom Co.,Ltd. Pen and multitouch sensor Pen eraser     id: 14  type: ERASER
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you explain what the method you tried from the internet?

Comment: https://www.linux-apps.com/content/download.php?content=104309 ... https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wacom/LatestDriver ... http://www.ubuntugeek.com/wacom-control-panel-easily-configure-wacom-tablet.html ... http://linuxwacom.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Libwacom ... but after automatically appeared WacomSettings at Ubuntu16 installation - it seems that for Kubuntu must be some much easy way to get those WacomSettings for ControlPanel..... but how???